# Missing Table "webpages_OAuthMembership"

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am using ASP.NET and WebSecurity. Here I try to initialize the database in my _AppStart.cshtml file calling: `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DecisionMaker", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", true);`

After this I call: `WebSecurity.CreateAccount(account, password);` and get the following exception:

```
    System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Unbekannter Fehler.
  Source=WebMatrix.WebData
  StackTrace:
       bei WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)
       bei WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)
       bei ASP._Page_Account_Register_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Dvp\DecisionMaker\Website\Account\Register.cshtml:Zeile 8.
       bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
       bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       bei System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       bei System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
  InnerException:
```

I think it has something to do with the table "webpages_OAuthMembership" cause in samples the table is automaticly generated and by my implementation it is missing.

My web.config file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DecisionMaker"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DecisionMaker.sdf;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership"
         value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"
                 targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks if someone out there can help me!